# How to spefic the body id attribute in JSF 2?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I need to set the `id` attribute of the html `body`-tag (for selenium test). But that JSF 2 `body` tag (`<h:body>`) has no `id` attribute.

So, how can I specify the `id` attribute for the html body in JSF 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`<h:body>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/body.html) does indeed not support it (admittedly also to my surprise; it's perfectly valid in HTML). I have reported it to the JSF guys as [issue 2409](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2409).

In the meanwhile, assuming that you're using Mojarra, you could solve this by extending Mojarra's `BodyRenderer` as follows:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.BodyRenderer;

public class BodyWithIdRenderer extends BodyRenderer {

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        super.encodeBegin(context, component);

        if (component.getId() != null) {
            context.getResponseWriter().writeAttribute("id", component.getClientId(context), "id");
        }
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register it as follows in `faces-config.xml` (no, the `@FacesRenderer` annotation magic won't work as to overriding the standard renderers).

```xml
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Body</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.BodyWithIdRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Comment: Hi, it seems to work like a charm, but when I try mvn install outside of eclipse, I get the following error: package com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic does not exist. Any idea?

Comment: @Alex: sorry, Maven is beyond me and this is offtopic to the concrete question being asked. Press `Ask Question` button to ask a new question.

Comment: @Alex: oh, please note that issue 2409 has as per the linked ticket been fixed since Mojarra 2.1.8. You might as well just upgrade it in order to use `<h:body id>` :)