# How to use <p:blockUI> on whole view?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I want to use `<p:blockUI>` to block the whole view. But as it's attribute `block` does only accept ids as keywords and not e.g. `@all`, the only way I currently see is to have a naming container (e.g. `<f:subview>`) to wrap the whole content of the view.

Unfortunately that's semantically dirty and I would need to rename all absolute ids because a new unneccessary (except for `<p:blockUI>`) id-"prefix" has been created.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I understand correctly, you could simply add an id to `h:body` and reference that id in the `block` attribute of `<p:blockUI>`. Also, you wouldn't need to change the ids of your components. Quick example

```
<h:body id="wholeView">  
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText/><br/>
        <h:inputText/><br/>
        <p:commandButton id="pnlBtn" value="Block Panel" type="button" onclick="bui.show()"/>  
        <p:blockUI block=":wholeView" widgetVar="bui"/>  
    </h:form>     
</h:body>
```

Again, this is just a silly example which simply blocks the view for demonstration purposes. However, from what I understand from the answer below, you would need to be using  Mojarra 2.1.8 or higher to use the id from `h:body`.

[How to spefic the body id attribute in JSF 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451424/how-to-spefic-the-body-id-attribute-in-jsf-2)

Comment: Oh yes! After upgrading Mojarra this was simple. Thank you. :)