# Where is onresize for <h:body> in JSF2.0

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I'm upgrading my old webapp from JSF1.X to JSF2.X. In the tutorials I've seen that I must replace `<body>` by `<h:body>`. The problem is that I used a javascript method to calculate height when I resized the window of my browser (`<body onresize="myFunction()">`). unfortunately, onresize event does not exist for `<h:body>`. 
Any idea I can solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `window.onresize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JSF 2.2, you could make use of passthrough attributes.

```
<html ... xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
...
<h:body a:onresize="foo()">
```

If you're using 2.0 (which is over 5 years old already), then you can't go around a custom renderer for `HtmlBody`. A kickoff example can be found here: [How to spefic the body id attribute in JSF 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451424/how-to-spefic-the-body-id-attribute-in-jsf-2/)

However, there are 2 (minor) problems with this approach of having `<body onresize>`:

1. You're supposed to hook it to the `window` in JS, not on `<body>` in HTML.

   ```
   window.onresize = foo();
   ```
2. You're supposed to keep the amount of JavaScript code in a (X)HTML document to an absolute minumum and put it as much as possible in its own JS file. So, prefer a real JS file over `on***` attribtues (like as that you should prefer a real CSS file over `style` attribute).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I fixed the issue with your help and adding the following code in the head part of the jspx:
`<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onresize = myfunction;
</script>`