# Primefaces BlockUI blocks all with widgetvar

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, blockui

i want use Primefaces BlockUI's widgetvar (at the moment i use a modal dialog for it). The application should block only when i select something (a long method will call) and unblock after complete. But it blocks the full side on first side access. Make i something wrong?

When i block the table specific it works. (`block="table"`) But i want block the whole page.

Use Primefaces 5.1 & Mojarra 2.2.8

Short example:

**xhtml:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<title>test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<h:form>

    <p:blockUI widgetVar="block" blocked="false"/>
    <p:dataTable id="table" value="#{myController.tableItems}" rowKey="#{data}"
        selection="#{myController.selectedItem}" selectionMode="Single"
        var="data">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" onstart="PF('block').show()"
            listener="#{myController.doSomething}"
            oncomplete="PF('block').hide()" />


        <p:column>#{data}</p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Bean:**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class MyController implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<String> tableItems;

private String selectedItem;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    tableItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    tableItems.add("test1");
    tableItems.add("test2");
}

public void doSomething(SelectEvent event){
    System.out.println("DO Something");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

public String getSelectedItem() {
    return selectedItem;
}

public void setSelectedItem(String selectedItem) {
    this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
}

public List<String> getTableItems() {
    return tableItems;
}

public void setTableItems(List<String> tableItems) {
    this.tableItems = tableItems;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _"But it blocks the full side on first side access."_

Comment: I cant select something in the table. The table is "blocked".

Comment: What is _first side access_

Comment: Sry i mean when i open the page and try to select in the table. This dont work anymore with blockui. When set a block target on table it works fine but i wanna lock the whole page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `id` attribute the body and use that in the `block=` attribute on the blockui component

Comment: thx. My h:body has no attribute id. I try it with this  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451424/how-to-spefic-the-body-id-attribute-in-jsf-2) but didnt work. Now i have a outputPanel unter the body that blocks the whole content.

Comment: Ohhh wow.. did not no that either. You could also have tried to add a class and use a PrimeFaces selector @(.myclass) in the target attribute. Might have worked to

Comment: @Kukeltje It doesn't work if the page is using a template and the body tag is in the said template.